# IntelliJ IDEA - Flex Debugger can't connect

Tags: apache, apache-flex, debugging, intellij-idea, flash

When I try to debug a flex application, debugging doesn't work.
I've got the debug player installed and playerversion.com says that I use the WIN 11,4,402,287 (Debug player).

After terminating the app, my IDEA console says:

```
Adobe fdb (Flash Player Debugger) [build 21328]
Copyright (c) 2004-2007 Adobe, Inc. All rights reserved.
Waiting for Player to connect
Failed to connect; session timed out.
Ensure that:
1. you compiled your Flash movie with debugging on, and
2. you are running the Debugger version of the Flash Player.
```

I compile with debugging on, and as I said, I use the debug player.

Any ideas?

Greetz

Comment: have you read this? http://forums.adobe.com/thread/672635 It is for Flash Builder but you might give it a try. If you create a new project, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: read it, nothing helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your compiler options are not overridden from somewhere else. Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom compiler config file, this file will override the compiler options menu.

And guess what, debug was set to false in that file...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure port 7935 isn't blocked by anything.  Debugging works through a port open by the debug player.

See docs here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=debugging_02.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Air, check that the path to airglobal.swc is correct in any compiler config file you might be using (mine was set wrong in project.xml)